# How to not need to rewrite SET search_path = ag_catalog every time

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Every time I run postgres instance, I need to manually set the **search_path** to be to ag_catalog by `SET search_path=ag_catalog;` and then load the age, is there a way makes me don't need to every time to do that?

Comment: "*Every time I run postgres instance*" - how are you doing that? What exactly do you mean by "run"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default schema/search_path is 'public'. In order to change the default search_path to 'ag_catalog' instead of public, you need to make a change to the `postgresql.conf` file inside your db cluster folder. You need to uncomment and change the search_path as

```
search_path = 'ag_catalog, "$user", public' # schema names
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it every time unless you change the default configuration in your `postgresql.conf` file.

To edit `postgresql.conf`:

1. Navigate to your postgresql directory then navigate to data folder.
2. Open `postgresql.conf` file.
3. Search for `search_path` attribute then uncomment it and add `ag_catalog`.

```
search_path = '"$user", public,ag_catalog'  # schema names
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `age` in only one database in the cluster you can set the `search_path` for just that database and not change the global setting.

From here [Alter Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html)

> The remaining forms change the session default for a run-time configuration variable for a PostgreSQL database. Whenever a new session is subsequently started in that database, the specified value becomes the session default value. The database-specific default overrides whatever setting is present in postgresql.conf or has been received from the postgres command line. Only the database owner or a superuser can change the session defaults for a database. Certain variables cannot be set this way, or can only be set by a superuser.

This means you can do:

```
ALTER DATABASE the_db SET search_path = ag_catalog;
```

If you need to undo that then:

```
ALTER DATABASE the_db SET search_path = default;
```

to get back to the `postgresql.conf` setting.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cluster, a folder with the same name as the cluster is created in the PostgreSQL directory. Within this folder, there is a file named `postgresql.conf`. Open this file using a text editor and locate the line that contains the term "search_path." Remove the '#' symbol at the beginning of the line to uncomment it. Then, modify the line to set the value of `search_path` as follows:

```
search_path = 'ag_catalog, "$user", public'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answers, to set the search_path directly from the terminal, use vim to edit the `postgresql.conf` file. From the installed postgres directory:

```
vim {cluster_name}/postgresql.conf
```

Once the editor opens up, type `/search_path` to jump to the line that needs to be modified. Press `i` to switch to 'INSERT' mode, which allows you to insert or delete characters. Once the change has been made, hit `esc` to get out of 'INSERT' mode, then press `:wq` to write and exit the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Open postgresql.conf file of the database using any text editor. Make respective changes in the required field. In this case add ag_catalog in the search_path var.

Save the file and restart server.

Note: Sometimes this does not work even when the file is changed so you'll have to find another method in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this by updating the `postgresql.conf` file in the database directory which you created using your preferred editor. Uncomment and add the required data in the file like so:

```
# you can also avoid loading age everytime using the statement below
shared_preload_libraries = 'age'

# To set the path
search_path = 'ag_catalog, "$user", public'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you not to `SET` the `search_path` to `ag_catalog` everytime you run an instance of Postgres, you have to edit you configuration file which is the `postgresql.conf` file, set the `search_path` to `'ag_catalog, "$user", public'` and save the file.